# Indexing software used in salesforce

Tags: search, indexing

Which indexing software is used by salesforce to index terms ? Is it lucene, Solr , ElasticSearch or something else ?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit where and under which circumstances answer for this question can be used (except if you plan work for SF)?

Answer (score 9):

Salesforce doesn't provide a lot of visibility into the inner workings and technologies underpinning their platform.

The official [engineering](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/) and [developer relations](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/) blogs may provide *some* insight from time to time, but again, it's not too substantial.

In the end, details like these are unimportant to end users like ourselves. Even if we knew which technologies Salesforce was using, we couldn't modify/upgrade/change/tune it ourselves.

That said, there was a session at Dreamforce '16 where someone within Salesforce did go over some of the tech that Salesforce does use (or is looking to use...it was an early session, and I don't remember it all). [The Future of Scale at Salesforce](https://success.salesforce.com/Sessions?eventId=a1Q3000000qQOd9EAG#/session/a2q3A000000sWKJQA2) (video autoplays). Apache Solr was mentioned as being used for indexing.

+edit: New link for the video, https://www.salesforce.com/video/295712/

Comment: Nice video link!

Answer (score 7):

As you know, Salesforce has different services and sites.

For the Salesforce Platform, as mentioned by @Derek F, and the [video](https://success.salesforce.com/Sessions?eventId=a1Q3000000qQOd9EAG#/session/a2q3A000000sWKJQA2) he pointed out:

1. Apache Solr (screenshot from the presentation below):
   [image]
2. For the [H&T Portal](https://help.salesforce.com/), Salesforce uses a [Coveo](http://www.coveo.com) Index.